# Is there a way to find the image id/url of an image, if you only have the url of the deleted album that the image was in? (Imgur unregistered upload)

Tags: imgur

I made an upload to imgur.com without an account, and then I deleted the post, but the image inside the post remains.

Is there any way to get the urls/deleteHash of images in previously deleted posts/albums, if I only have the url to the deleted posts/albums, not the urls of the individual images inside those posts/albums?

Example:
Album/post was deleted: https://imgur.com/a/YD7loi6
Image inside the post/album remains: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9xGj.jpg